# Wordpress: Registration & Analytics

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I am having a strange problem.

Google analytics is not able to track user registration. When I try it myself, it works but for no other user.

I get lot of emails on registration but no action/data in analytics.

Anyone knows about this issue and solution for it.

FYI: This is new website and hence there is no analytics data but user registrations are happening on daily basis.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a plugin to track in Analytics? Is configured correctly? Are there in Analytics the navigation data of the users registered?

Comment: No plugin used. Just analytics from google.
When I try to do registration as user, my visit is recorded with bounce rate.

I have wordfence installed too and I get lot of user logged in & locked out messages too. But nothing on analytics.

Do you think, there is some other process bypassing website?

FYI : I am using ultimate member for user registration and login. Plus, disabled backend login.php with a htaccess redirect to home page.

Comment: I don't understand if the tracking is there or not. Is the registration tracked with a goal or is there a dedicated page you check in page report?

Comment: This is regular wordpress page with ultimate member shortcode.

It is tracked just like any other page and yes, it has tracking code too.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So, is the registration tracked with a goal? How do you see your registration on Analytics? Can you post the screenshot of the goal configuration?

Comment: Well, for now, I am only tracking visits / page views.  No data yet.

Comment: Google Anlaytics cannot understand for itself whether a user is signing up for your site. In this case you must send to Analytics a particular event or a virtual page when an has registered. On that hit you can set the goal in Analytics and see it in the analysis platform.

Comment: As I mentioned in my last comment, I am looking for page visits for now. Registration page has the analytics code too. Ideally, it should record the visit if users are registering, but it is not. This give rise to: Are people using some other mechanism to register? (No, others have been blocked). Does analytics needs multi-visits in order to track or one page visit is enough?

Comment: If you have a registration page, i.e. /regitration-successfully you should see that in Google Analytics. If you have more users registered in CRM than in Analytics it is normal, there are various reasons. But in your previous messages you wrote that none of those registered are in Analytics, this is not normal. So, is there a dedicated landing page after registration? How do you see those who are registered? Is there a JavaScript error in the console on that page? Is the code positioned in the correct position (head)?

Comment: Thanks for being with me on this. Mine is little different perspective to this problem. I am not tracking registration counts. I am just looking for page views (as of right now) This also means that each time page (any page) is accessed by a user, analytics will kick in. And hence will show a user visited the website. All the pages have the code in body (not head).

Comment: My concern here is that Users are getting registered still analytics says "0 Users" accessed the website.------------ Where as, when I access the website and run through number of pages, it gets reflected. This is mind boggling.

Comment: Can you provide me the url of your website, pls?

Comment: giftmydream.com

Comment: Added GTM now, hope this one works.

Comment: I can't see any Analytics code on the page and about GTM I don't know if you are configured it but it is definitely not published. The site is not tracking anything.